# Quick .htaccess fix with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

There is an error on my .htaccess file. On my index page, I have a PHP that checks what the $_GET['page'] is, and it returns `index.php` when I type in `domain.com/home`.

I want it to return as home when I type in `domain.com/home`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep your rules from looping. Try adding a condition that prevents rewrite if the URI is already `index.php`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Lin. Worked like a charm